# Evaluating a defined function at points in a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a defined function and a set of points I am looking to get numerical results from when applied to my function. I have looked around online and not seen a method that will run my code and give decimal answers.

```
P0:= 3000
t0:= 63072000
Pd[t_]:=0.0622*P0*(t^-0.02 - (t0 + t)^-0.02)
pts = {86400, 604800, 2678400, 31536000}
```

For context I am trying to calculate the decay heat from a nuclear system following its shutdown at various times.

Comment: Try `Map[Pd, pts]`

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is the `Map` function

> `Map[f,expr]` or `f/@expr`
>   applies `f` to each element on the first level in `expr`.

Thus:

```
In[1]:= Map[f, {a, b, c, d, e}]
Out[1]= {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e]}
```

or alternatively:

```
In[1]:= f /@ {a, b, c, d, e}
Out[1]= {f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e]}
```